# How to show decimals only on file sizes greater or equal to 1 MB?

Tags: c#, humanizer

With `Humanizer`, is there any built-in way to display a `file size < 1 MB` without any decimals and display a `file size >= 1 MB` with 1 or 2 decimals? Or does one need to write a custom method for that?

Comment: [filesize](https://github.com/HubSpot/humanize#filesize)

Comment: This looks like what I want, but I am on C# (https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) where this is not available.

Comment: How are you loading the data onto your webpage? Are you assigning a value to a Label or are you exposing it in a DataBinder / Eval ?

Comment: What about this: [bytesize](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#bytesize)?

Comment: @Stephen85 In a blazor web app using `@File.Size`

Comment: @MaciejLos: that's what I also found but I am missing the functionality of filesize. For bytesize I still have to decide myself that KB shall be shown without decimals. Wondering if I missed something or there is really no builtin method for that.